# is there any solution for this selling manger issue

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

I am working on a basic selling manager

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from tkinter import filedialog

screen = Tk()
screen.title("Buyer")
screen.geometry("800x600")
w = Frame(screen)
w.grid(padx=1, pady=1)
w.pack(pady=5)

def Add_image():
    add_image.destroy()
    image =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/yasse/OneDrive/Documents",
               filetypes=(("all","*.*"),("PNG","*.png"),("JPEG", "*.jpeg"),("GIF", "*.gif")))
    Image.open(image).resize(size=(50,40))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    lbl = Label(w, image=photo).grid(column=0)

add_image = Button(w, text="+", font=("helvetica", 30), command= Add_image)
add_name = Entry(w, font=("helvetica", 13))
add_price = Entry(w, font=("helvetica", 13))
add_quantity = Entry(w, font=("helvetica", 16), width=5)

class product:
    def __init__(self, image, name, price, quantity):
        self.image = image
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity
    def product_row(self, row):
        self.image.grid(column=0, row=row, padx=30, pady=15)
        self.name.grid(column=1, row=row, padx=30, pady=15)
        self.price.grid(column=2, row=row,padx=30, pady=15)
        self.quantity.grid(column=3, row=row, padx=30, pady=15)
def selling():
    buying_button.destroy()
    selling_button.destroy()
    screen.title("selling mode")
    product1 = product(add_image, add_name, add_price, add_quantity)
    product1.product_row(row=0)
    product2 = product(add_image, add_name, add_price, add_quantity)
    product2.product_row(row=1)
    product3 = product(add_image, add_name, add_price, add_quantity)
    product3.product_row(row=2)

buying_button = Button(w, text="buyer mode",font=("helvetica", 16), width=16, height=2)
selling_button = Button(w, text="seller mode",font=("helvetica", 16), width=16, height=2, 
                                                                        command= selling)
selling_button.pack()
buying_button.pack()

screen.mainloop()
```

so this code should create a multiple rows of products but for some reason only one product appears and I want also to replace the add_image button with the image but the image doesn't
appears also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should fix both your bugs:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

screen = Tk()
screen.title("Buyer")
screen.geometry("800x600")
w = Frame(screen)
w.grid(padx=1, pady=1)
w.pack(pady=5)

def Add_image(sender, row):
    image =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/yasse/OneDrive/Documents",
            filetypes=(("all","*.*"),("PNG","*.png"),("JPEG", "*.jpeg"),("GIF", "*.gif")))
    
    img = Image.open(image).resize(size=(50,40))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    btn = ttk.Button(w, image=photo)
    btn.image = photo
    btn.grid(column=0, row=row)
    sender.destroy()

class product:
    def __init__(self, image, name, price, quantity):
        self.image = image
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity
    def product_row(self, row):
        self.image.configure(command=lambda: Add_image(self.image, row)) 
        self.image.grid(column=0, row=row, padx=30, pady=15)
        self.name.grid(column=1, row=row, padx=30, pady=15)
        self.price.grid(column=2, row=row,padx=30, pady=15)
        self.quantity.grid(column=3, row=row, padx=30, pady=15)

def create_product():
    add_image = Button(w, text="+", font=("helvetica", 30))
    add_name = Entry(w, font=("helvetica", 13))
    add_price = Entry(w, font=("helvetica", 13))
    add_quantity = Entry(w, font=("helvetica", 16), width=5)
    return product(add_image, add_name, add_price, add_quantity)

def selling():
    buying_button.destroy()
    selling_button.destroy()
    screen.title("selling mode")
    product1 = create_product()
    product1.product_row(row=0)
    product2 = create_product()
    product2.product_row(row=1)
    product3 = create_product()
    product3.product_row(row=2)

buying_button = Button(w, text="buyer mode",font=("helvetica", 16), width=16, height=2)
selling_button = Button(w, text="seller mode",font=("helvetica", 16), width=16, height=2, 
                                                                        command=selling)
selling_button.pack()
buying_button.pack()

screen.mainloop()
```

The problem with the grid was due to the fact that, by giving all the products the same instances of buttons and entries, the rows where overlapped, because when you changed the row number of say a button, you were changing the row of ALL buttons. Giving each product a different instance of the inputs, I fixed this problem.

In case you can't understand any edit I made, pls let me know

Comment: thx for answering me, well i didn't get two points:                                                                    1- the "sender" thing                                                                                                                        2-and this line "self.image.configure(command=lambda: Add_image(self.image, row))"

Comment: and u import "Imageshow" but u didn't actually use it , i think this why the pictures are not showing up when i add them

Comment: 1 - Sender) The 'sender' is a parameter that I added to know which button called the function. Having multiple buttons, you have to know where to put the image.

2) 'self.image.configure(...)' is needed to add the command to the button after the creation of the instance. I had to do this way so that I could pass the function both the instance of the button itself and the row of the button.

Comment: I have just fixed the code, so that pictures are actually shown.